# Finding an integer in a list of integers if condition fulfilled

Tags: python

So I have a df with three columns: The first contains a name, the second an ID, and the third a list of IDs (delimited by commas). For guys with an identical name in the first column, I'd like to check if the ID in the second column of the one guy appears in the list of IDs in the third column of the other guy.

```
name   id   id2

Gabor  665  123
Hoak   667  100,111,112
Sherr  668  1,2,3
Hoak   669  667,500,600
Rine   670  73331,999
Rine   671  670,15
```

So basically I'd like python to note that there's two guys called "Hoak" and check if the id 667 of Hoak No.1 appears in the other Hoak's id2-list (which it does). I've tried to start with a cheap approach that does it manually for whatever name I specify, let's say for "Hoak" (i=1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (...)

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['name'][i] == df['name'][1]:
        if df['id'][1] in df['id2'][i]:
            print(i)
```

However, I'm getting

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

I've tried to add all sorts of variations, like *.string* or *str()*, or things like if *(df['id2'][i]).str.contains("667")*, but I can't work it out, getting erros like

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'string'

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which column is being interpreted as a float?

Comment: @Triggernometry based off of the code, it looks like it is the init `df` as the error states the float is not iterable... Meaning the for-loop is trying to iterate on that segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pandas-style approach is to group the rows by name and see if the set of all IDs in each group intersects with the set of all ID2s in the same group:

```
df['id2'] = df['id2'].astype(str).str.split(',').apply(set)
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str) # if needed
df.groupby('name')\
  .apply(lambda x: set(x['id']) & set.union(*x['id2']))
#name
#Gabor       {}
#Hoak     {667}
#Rine     {670}
#Sherr       {}
```

Comment: @T.Woody Jumble? Pardon me? The OP, no matter what level they are, should learn how to solve problems correctly. If they are mature enough to use DataFrames, they should be mature enough to use them correctly.

Comment: Running your code, I still get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` and

`File "<ipython-input-95-42354aaa7e1a>", line 1, in <module> df['id2'] = df['id2'].str.split(',').apply(set)` and `File C:\(...)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3591, in apply mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)` and 
`File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2217, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer`

Comment: @Stphn Does any of your `id2`s have a decimal point instead of a comma? Or is a comma the decimal separator in your native language? What does `float(2,3)` report?

Comment: float(2,3) returns `TypeError: float expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`. That shouldnt be the case right? The decimal separator in Switzerland is a point.

Comment: That should be the case. So, one way or another, at least one of the values in `df['id2']` is not a string. Check my updated answer: does it work now?

Comment: Looks like someone removed my  comment. I still stand by it. If we strive for perfection at every step, we will never get anywhere. I am sorry to offend, but this answer is simply to complicated for OP's understanding. OP needs to learn to debug first and foremost.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much already. I've to test now if it does what I need it to do. The problem is that I have many "Hoaks" in the first column, and just a few are linked with each other through their IDs, In the end, I'll need the code to tell me that Hoak 667 and 669 are linked, but not (hypothetical) Hoak with id 680.

Comment: As you can see from the results, the code fragment reports the IDs of the linked persons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `dtype` in `read_excel` to avoid float problems.

> Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(io="test.xls", header=0, dtype={'name': np.str, 'id': np.str, 'id2': np.str})

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['name'][i] == df['name'][1]:
        if df['id'][1] in df['id2'][i]:
            print(i)
```

Next you need correct the search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

try chaging this condition

```
if df['id'][1] in df['id2'][i]:
```

with this

```
if isinstance(df['id2'][i], list) and df['id'][1] in df['id2'][i]:
     ...
elif df['id'][1] == df['id2'][i] : 
     ...
```

the problem is maybe that when you go through rows with one value only it wont take it as a list but as a float value, so you can't iterate through it

Answer (score -1):

`df = pd.read_excel` is showing up as a float, per your error messages. Have you tried to just print out the `i` at your first loop? Work your way down through your nested for-loops once that bug is gone.

To solve the first bug, you need to set `dtype` in `read_excel` to avoid float problems.

Comment: This must have been posted as a comment.

Comment: `for i in range(0,len(df)):`
   `if df['name'][i] == df['name'][3]:`
        `print(i)` 
printing out the i at first loop returns the values 1 and 3, which is correct, since "Hoak" is found in rows 1 and 3.

Comment: the values 1 and 3 are being printed out, jap

Comment: @Stphn see norbeq 's answer above.